# How to map inner classes in automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to transfer the information of a string in an inner class with automapper. How can I get the value of D?
My first attempt was:

```
C = new C { D = "123"}
```

This failed in dotnetfiddle, so what would be the right approach?

Is it even possible to Map an inner class to another object or is it necessary to change the mapping in order of it to work?

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

public class Foo
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }  
    public class C
    {
        public string D {get;set;}
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public class C 
    {
        public string D {get;set;}
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()       
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>();

        var foo = new Foo { A="test", B=100500}; //how to get c/d?

        var bar = Mapper.Map<Bar>(foo);

        Console.WriteLine("foo type is {0}", foo.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("bar type is {0}", bar.GetType());

        Console.WriteLine("foo.A={0} foo.B={1}", foo.A, foo.B);
        Console.WriteLine("bar.A={0} bar.B={1}", bar.A, bar.B);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to map here. You have nested class *declaration*. It's not data. You should have a field or property of nested class type:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public C Value { get; set; } // add same to Bar class
    public class C
    {
        public string D { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next you need mapping between nested classes:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo.C,Bar.C>();
```

And data to map:

```
var foo = new Foo { A ="test", B = 100500, Value = new Foo.C { D = "foo" }};
```

Mapping:

```
var bar = Mapper.Map<Bar>(foo);
```

After mapping `bar` object will have following values:

```
{
  "A": "test",
  "B": 100500,
  "Value": {
    "D": "foo"
  }
}
```

Further reading: [Nested Types Best Practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229027%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks I've bamboozled myself with that one. If I add you suggestions I'm getting the following error: Run-time exception (line 33): Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Foo -> Bar
Foo -> Bar

Destination path:
Bar

Source value:
Foo

Comment: @Zoba have you tried my code? It maps foo to bar with value of nested class C. You are probably doing something which is not stated in my answer

Comment: it must've been an error in dotnetfiddle. Copying the code into a clean vs2015 project worked for me. I've marked your answer as a solution to my problem. Thanks!